# Ubuntu MATE does not respond repeatedly

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I am running Ubuntu MATE (ubuntu version 20.04.4LTS, MATE 1.24.0) and it repeatedly freezes or stop responding, at least for a while (at least once I waited enough and it started responding again). This means that the keyboard seems to be ignored, and the mouse, althoug its pointer can be moved, ignres the click too.

I connected via ssh from another computer, and I could check through the terminal it was working. I don't know if it is a common issue and at least I would like to know if  there any way to know what could be failing (for instance searching in a certain log file).

This occurs frequently and it does not seem to be associated to any particular action (I could be using the browser or libre office for example).
Thanks

Comment: what hardware are you using? can you check memory and CPU usage when the desktop environment freezes using ssh?

Comment: I'm using an old MacBook Pro with an Intel Core 2 Duo and 4g of ram. `free -m` through ssh shows that less than half memory is in use.

Comment: how about `top`?

Comment: some ideas here https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-a-frozen-mate-linux-desktop/ sounds like the issue is with MATE, since you can use a terminal fine while the DE is crashed

Answer (score -1):

So I continued doing some tests and it seems that it is not a MATE issue. I tryied installing Ubuntu 22.04 and the issue repreoduced. Also, I installed Arch linux and used xfce4 and the issue occured also.

At the end, as I was always testing using firefox and libreoffice y removed both and installed google chrome and wps office and then it stopped.